# C# and LINQ - arbitrary statement instead of let

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

Let's say I'm doing a LINQ query like this (this is LINQ to Objects, BTW):

```
var rows = 
    from t in totals
    let name = Utilities.GetName(t)
    orderby name
    select t;
```

So the `GetName` method just calculates a display name from a `Total` object and is a decent use of the `let` keyword. But let's say I have another method, `Utilities.Sum()` that applies some math on a `Total` object and sets some properties on it. I can use `let` to achieve this, like so:

```
var rows =
    from t in totals
    let unused = Utilities.Sum(t)
    select t;
```

The thing that is weird here, is that `Utilities.Sum()` has to return a value, even if I don't use it. Is there a way to use it inside a LINQ statement if it returns `void`? I obviously can't do something like this:

```
var rows =
    from t in totals
    Utilities.Sum(t)
    select t;
```

PS - I know this is probably not *good* practice to call a method with side effects in a LINQ expression. Just trying to understand LINQ syntax completely.

Comment: Use a `foreach`, it's what it's there for.

Comment: Not sure why you want to use **Utilities** object to get the *name* or *sum* of **t** object... Linq provides functionality to get data in a specific order or to use aggregate functions. I think, you mixed old way to access data with new one. Note, you can join data, if there is a relationship between **Totals** and **Utilities**.

Comment: @MaciejLos The `Utilities` class in my example is summing several properties on the same object. The `Sum` method in LINQ sums a sequence of values in an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answering the question

No, but you could cheat by creating a `Func` which just calls the intended method and spits out a random return value, `bool` for example:

```
Func<Total, bool> dummy = (total) => 
    { 
        Utilities.Sum(total);
        return true;
    };

var rows = from t in totals
           let unused = dummy(t)
           select t;
```

But this is not a good idea - it's not particularly readable.

---

#### The let `statement` behind the scenes

What the above query will translate to is something similar to this:

```
var rows = totals.Select(t => new { t, unused = dummy(t) })
                 .Select(x => x.t);
```

So another option if you want to use method-syntax instead of query-syntax, what you could do is:

```
var rows = totals.Select(t =>
               {
                   Utilities.Sum(t);
                   return t;
               });
```

A little better, but still abusing LINQ.

---

#### ... but what you should do

But I really see no reason not to just simply loop around totals separately:

```
foreach (var t in totals)
    Utilities.Sum(t);
```

Comment: So what do you do if you have multiple `unused` variables? Name them `unused1`, `unused2`, `unused3`...

Comment: Change this to `where dummy(t)`

Comment: @jonathanpeppers Are you like trying to pull a prank on a co-worker or something by turning their code into an unmanagable mess?

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to name the variables `__1`, `__2`, `__3`, all the way up to 50 if I need to. LOL

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no LINQ method that performs an `Action` on all of the items in the `IEnumerable<T>`.  It was [very specifically left out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) because the designers actively didn't want it to be in there.

Comment: I'm not wanting to perform an action on an `IEnumerable`. I want to put an arbitrary expression in the middle of a LINQ statement.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers You're using different words to say exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the "Interactive Extensions" (NuGet `Ix-Main`) from Microsoft's Reactive Extensions team. It has a load of useful extensions. It'll let you do this:

```
var rows =
    from t in totals.Do(x => Utilities.Sum(x))
    select t;
```

It's there to allow side-effects on a traversed enumerable.

Answer (score -1):

Please, read my comment to the question. The simplest way to achieve such of functionality is to use query like this:

```
var rows = from t in totals
    group t by t.name into grp
    select new 
    {
        Name = t.Key,
        Sum = grp.Sum()
    };
```

Above query returns *IEnumerable* object.

For further information, please see: [101 LINQ Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)